# Working setup for MySQL HA & LB

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

I have to setup `High Availability` and `Load balancing` for web(apache-tomcat+mod_jk) and MySQL(where all clients info is stored) server which are running on the same machine(ubuntu server). First I am trying to setup for the MySQL databases with minimal setup of servers(2 or 3).

I heard about `master-slave` setup which is not suitable for HA as there is some down time while making the slave a master when master is down.

I also heard about the `master-master` setup and is said to have some disadvantages like conflicting problems.

Anybody know any reliable and best setup which could be implemented for production?

**EDIT 1**:

I have checked setting up `master-master` and `master-slave` and didn't see any problem or trouble giving in syncing over LAN and I'm not sure these works flawless on production systems. I heard load balancing of mysql databases are possible and may not be possible and I'm not sure of this.

I heard about `mysql cluster 7` and seems to be powerful of all the available options but I could not find any proper documentation setup.

Comment: If you cannot afford the down time necessary to switch a slave to master mode, a strong argument could be made that you cannot afford to be using MySQL at all.  I know many people will hate me for saying that... But my experience tells me that MySQL really isn't designed for HA applications.  With enough redundancy, there are many successful HA MySQL installations that overcome (what I would consider to be) shortcomings in MySQL's design, though.

Comment: You may be right!, I'm asking how organizations setup HA & LB if they have to use ubuntu and mysql. I need the best and reliable method of available ways.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plethora of information on HA & LB for MySQL available on the web, and in print.  What research have you done so far?  I suggest starting [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-ha-scalability/en/index.html).

Comment: Mydear, even I can list many other ways but I'm asking the best and reliable method to stick with it. If you had setup anything and it's still running without any problem, let me know.

Comment: Any specify documents of any setup which works perfectly, the mysql documents are prolonging....

Comment: There's a lot of information, but few best-practice guides.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Tungsten Enterprise](http://www.continuent.com/solutions/tungsten-enterprise) or [Schooner Active Cluster](http://www.schoonerinfotech.com/products/active_cluster).

The strictly open source (read free) solutions can't really solve your problem. [MMM](http://mysql-mmm.org/) tries but it has come under scrutiny lately and is [not recommended](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2011/05/04/whats-wrong-with-mmm/) by one of the experts in the field.

You are going to have to shell out some dollars to solve your problem which kinda lends some weight to Flimzy's point that it may be prudent to consider other solutions on the DB tier.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I'll try them one day. Any opensource software/packages or I should adjust with master-slave.